In selecting lag orders of ARMA model, should I obey AIC or Ljung-Box?
I have 13 series of returns that I want to study through a GJR-GARCH model.
Since 3 of these have show mean autocorrelation (according to a Ljung-Box test) I need to get rid of it, and I decided to calculate the AIC for all combinations between ARMA(0,0) and ARMA(2,2).
Unexpectedly, the AIC suggests that the best model is ARMA(2,2) for 10 out of 13 series, regardless of autocorrelation detection by the Ljung-Box test.
My question is: What should I do about the non-autocorrelated series? Should I obey the AIC and use and ARMA(2,2) regardless, or should I obey the Ljung-Box test and use the ARMA(2,2) only for the series where autocorrelation has been detected by Ljung-Box?
EDIT: My final goal is to apply a GJR-GARCH to these 13 series and confront the leverage terms, so I have a related follow up question: If I apply different ARMA models to each series based on the AIC results, would this affect the comparability of the leverage terms? Or instead confronting GJR-GARCH coefficients obtained on residuals of different ARMA models would be like comparing apples and oranges?

AFAIK, there is nothing that says you shouldn't use (2,2) even if Ljung-Box doesn't require it.
